Debugging crash dump, call stack gives wrong line number
I'm attempting to debug a crash dump in Visual Studio 2019. However, the call stack is giving me the wrong line number for the method that calls the one in which the crash occurs.
A bit of background - I created this application on my own dev machine (Windows 11), built it on a build server (Windows 10 22H2) in Release mode, and ran it on a third machine (Windows 10 1607).
I then collected the dump from the crash (large dump - type "2") - which had been generated as I had set up HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps in the registry, brought it back to my own machine, and copied the PDB and EXE from the build server.
Now I open the dump file in Visual Studio 2019, and it shows my code and the program stopped at the line of the crash, showing the correct exception. See below (I've copied in screen shots rather than direct code so you can see the line numbers).

When I view the call stack, it shows it stopped at line #50 in my Crasher class, which is correct - see code below.

however it states that it was called from Line #27 in the Program.Main() class. When in fact, the line containing the call to the function is #25. Again, see below.

The funny thing is, if I view the exception details, the stack trace correctly points to line #25!
Why is the call stack giving an incorrect line number? The code files did not change after copying to the build server (it's line #25 there too).

Remember, the stack trace is a trace of return addresses, not caller addresses.

Line numbers are not reliable in the Release build.  A major reason why the Debug configuration exists and why by default the Release configuration creates a pdb without line number info.

In Release mode, the compiler applies various optimizations such as inlining, loop unrolling, and code reordering to improve performance.
So it is possible that the line that issued the error is different from the source code of your code. You can run your app in Debug mode and observe.
There are many examples about this:
wrong-exception-line-number-in-stack-trace-in-release-mode
wrong-line-numbers-in-stack-trace-release
